# Reusing code from my ASP.NET Core MVC app in console app : how to do database connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I did an ASP.NET Core MVC app working with the Web. This app read from and write to a database.

Now, I want to create a console app that uses the same database (server, connection string,...), also in .NET Core.

How can I reuse the code of the database context to access the same database than the first app?

For now, my Program.cs is the basic. I would like to insert here the code to prepare the database connection...

**EDIT**

My data context model is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MVFxml;
using MVFxml.Models;
using MVFxml.Models.ViewModels;
//using MVFxml.Controllers;
using MVFxml.Infrastructure;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVFxml.Models
{
    public class fmDataContext : DbContext
    {
        private DbContextOptions<fmDataContext> opt { get; set; }

        public fmDataContext(DbContextOptions<fmDataContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            opt = options;
        }

        public MyStructure RetrieveFromDb(long id = -1)
        {
           … code here …
        }

        ...other fuctions here...
}
```

Comment: Can you post the database code you used for the web project?

Comment: Data access isn't affected by the type of application. If you use DI in the console application, you can use exactly the same code and concepts. You can use `dotnet new worker` to create a console app with a generic host builder and a Startup.cs similar to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: you should create a class library and move your database related logic to that layer. then you can simply use that layer in other projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I wrote the `Main` routine of my console app as following:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            …
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<fmDataContext>();

            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(connectionString, providerOptions => providerOptions.CommandTimeout(60));

            using (fmDataContext context = new fmDataContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                MyStructure data = context.RetrieveFromDb();

                … // here I do whatever I want with the data
            }
```

And I didn't have to change my `fmDataContext` class shown above...